# How to write array with deleted image id?

Tags: reactjs

When i remove images from news i catch id, and id come to along. 
How to write in array all this lonlies id ? 
How to create streamIds array with streamId ?

```
this.state = {
            mainImage: null,
            mainImageUrl: "",
            crop: {
                aspect: 2 / 1
            },
            pixelCrop: null,
            cropped: false,
            loaded: false,
            streamIds: []
        };

removeImage(imageKey, streamId) {
        const {singleNews} = this.props;
    let streamIds = this.state.streamIds;
        console.log(streamId);

    singleNews.secondaryImages.splice(imageKey, 1);

    if (!singleNews.secondaryImages.length) {
        singleNews.secondaryImages = null;

        delete singleNews.secondaryImages;

        this.props.updateSingleNews(null, singleNews);
    } else {
        streamIds.push(streamId);
        singleNews.secondaryImages.map(image => {
            const index = singleNews.secondaryImages.indexOf(image);

            if (index > -1) {
                singleNews.secondaryImages.slice(index, 1);

                FilesApi.getDocument(image.streamId).then(resp => {
                    singleNews.secondaryImages[index] = new File([resp], image.name, {lastModified: Date.now()});
                });
            }

        });
        this.props.updateSingleNews('streamIds', streamIds);
    }
}
```

[this is your method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o10Xp.png)

If not in this func where i need to place

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the array of ids in the same component, use

```
let streamIds = [];
```

at the top of your react component and do

```
removeImage (imageKey, streamId) {
   console.log(streamId);
   streamIds.push(streamId); // insert the item to array
}
```

in your removeImage method

if you want to keep the removed ids in the application state, then the concept is the same, but it need to be done on the state management tool you are using (like redux, mobx etc)

Comment: Hello thnx but it push only one item and doesnt took next one, i add photo u can see it up. How to write all items in streamIds?

Comment: In your code you are declaring the array inside your removeImage method, which will  create a new array every time you call the method, please move that line 'let streamIds = [];' to the top of your component and as i shown in the code sample. then it will work if you are managing all from the same component,